# How to hide application title in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar, android-titlebar

I want to create an application with just the app icon on the title bar and no app name.  How can I do it?

I have tried to use:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

but it just removes the title bar and not just the application name.

Comment: Set title to empty string ""?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Call `setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)` on the `ActionBar` instance](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayShowTitleEnabled%28boolean%29) you get back by calling `getActionBar()` on your activity.

Comment: Note that to address Tushar Pandey's answer, there may be a way to disable the title via your activity's theme, but I have not researched that.

Comment: Wooo what a dream , common's ware is pointing me , ha ha you made my day !

Comment: @user1377504 , hey follow Sir Cyrils tutorial , he is a another master , http://cyrilmottier.com/2013/01/23/android-app-launching-made-gorgeous/

Answer (score 2):

How about this ?

```
setTitle("");
```

...in `onCreate()` of any Activity whose title should be empty. (Or in `onCreateView()` of any Fragment: `getActivity().setTitle("");`)

Comment: I don't know if there's much practical difference between these two, but [CommonsWare's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21065213/56285) does seem cleaner. I wasn't aware of `setDisplayShowTitleEnabled()`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not opposing , Sir ( Jonik/CommonsWare ) answer , but by doing `getActivity().setTitle("")` & `setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)` you will see app title at the creation of the  Activity , i think .

but if you perform Sir ( Jonik/CommonsWare ) answer like this , then it will be better

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

            super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

          if(hasFocus) 
             getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    }
```

Sorry if , it doesnt help you !

Comment: thanks for pointing it out.  I tried your solution as well but the app title is display for a millisecond and then it disappears.

Comment: Go and change your Android theme !